# values in dropdown according to rights

Tags: asp.net, linq, drop-down-menu, rights

I have login and webform1.aspx

values in dropdown

```
**values** 
apples
oranges
grapes
factory
juices
banana
Grapes
```

i want when i login with username admin and password then values in dropdown must be factory only where as when i login with other than this admin username then want to show other values except factory

and also when  i login with another username then values are in dropdown but not complete list only few values are display where as i want all values except factory

i try this sp and this sp works perfect

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[list]
as
select fruits from tblReg
where fruits <>'' and 
fruits not in ('Factory')
and fruits  not like '%[0-9]%'
group by fruits
```

and i convert this sp in linq 2nd query

on login form i do this

button click

```
            try
            {
                loginmethod(txt_us.Text, txt_pwd.Text);
                Response.Redirect("WebForm1.aspx");
                Session["UserName"] = txt_us.Text;
            }
            catch
            {
                Label1.Text = ("");
                Label1.Visible = false;
            }
```

login method

```
  private bool loginmethod(string UserName, string Password)
    {

       Entities2 td = new Entities2();
        splogin_Result sp = td.splogin(UserName, Password).FirstOrDefault();
        if (sp.Password == txt_pwd.Text)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }

  }
```

and on webform page load

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Entities2 tea = new Entities2(); 
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                if ((Session["UserName"] as string) == "admin")
                {
         //1st query 

regiondrop.DataSource = tea.tblReg.Where(x => x.Fruits== "Factory")
.Select(x => new { Fruits= x.Fruits, Value = x.Fruits}).Distinct()
 .ToList();

                }
                else
                { 
                 //2nd query 

          regiondrop.DataSource = tea.tblReg.AsEnumerable()
                               .Where(x => x.Fruits.All(char.IsLetter) &&
                                x.Fruits!= "" &&
                               x.Fruits!= "Factory")
                       .Select(x => new { Fruits=x.Fruits, Value=x.Fruits})
                       .Distinct().ToList();    
                }
                regiondrop.DataTextField = "Fruits";
                regiondrop.DataValueField = "Fruits";
                regiondrop.DataBind();
                Label4.Visible = false;

            }  

        }
```

Comment: what's the problem with your code?Is it not running or you are not getting you desired output.

Comment: yes @A_Name_Does_Not_Matter

Comment: what's the problem?

Comment: when i login with admin then all values are display in dropdown whereas i want value only factory when i login with admin @A_Name_Does_Not_Matter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you map table 'tblReg' with user role and pass Session["UserName"] or Session["role"] as parameter to SP and select values and display in ddl.Simply fetch data according to role.

Updated

Now add one column role(value = Admin or User) in tbllogin.

```
select role, UserName , Password from tbllogin where UserName=@UserName and Password=@Password
```

Store role in session(Session["role"]).

Now also add one column in tblReg and map with role
Eg

```
RegId   fruits        Role
  1      Mango        user
  2      Apple        Admin
  3      banana       Admin
```

You need to pass sql parameter from code behind

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[list]
@role varchar(10)
as
select fruits from tblReg
where role = @role
```

Finally bind in code without checking role again.

Comment: i create simple sp like this select UserName , Password from tbllogin
where 
UserName=@UserName and Password=@Password